# Python deep merge dictionary data

Tags: python

Is there a library in Python that I can use to deep merge dictionaries:

The following:

```
a = { 'first' : { 'all_rows' : { 'pass' : 'dog', 'number' : '1' } } }
b = { 'first' : { 'all_rows' : { 'fail' : 'cat', 'number' : '5' } } }
```

When i combine I want this to look like:

```
a = { 'first' : { 'all_rows' : { 'pass' : 'dog', 'fail' : 'cat', 'number' : '5' } } }
```

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/python-dictionaries-of-dictionaries-merge

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I hope I don't reinvent the wheel but the solution is fairly short. And, superfun to code.

```
def merge(source, destination):
    """
    run me with nosetests --with-doctest file.py

    >>> a = { 'first' : { 'all_rows' : { 'pass' : 'dog', 'number' : '1' } } }
    >>> b = { 'first' : { 'all_rows' : { 'fail' : 'cat', 'number' : '5' } } }
    >>> merge(b, a) == { 'first' : { 'all_rows' : { 'pass' : 'dog', 'fail' : 'cat', 'number' : '5' } } }
    True
    """
    for key, value in source.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # get node or create one
            node = destination.setdefault(key, {})
            merge(value, node)
        else:
            destination[key] = value

    return destination
```

So the idea is to copy the source to the destination, and every time it's a dict in the source, recurse. So indeed you will have a bug if in A a given element contains a dict and in B any other type.

[EDIT] as said in comments the solution was already here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7205107/34871

Comment: This is excellent and yes - fun. Should have taken a closer look at the DUP earlier. Nice use of recursion. From brief testing, it seems fit for purpose. The data i'm working with is always of type dict in a or b.

Comment: +1 - This seems a lot more straight forward that the DUP one in the case that we don't care about conflicts

Comment: Just beware that this is modifying the `destination` dict *in place!*

Comment: What @Arel said. It would probably make sense to remove the return statement, as it's a bit deceptive.

Comment: Fails with case: ({'b': {'c': 1}}, {'b': 1}), as {'b': {'c': 1}} is expected. Fix is to check for primitive types after setdefault, and default to {} if so.

Comment: The code does not produce the result documented in the comment. The result has 'number':'1' not 'number':'5'. Either the comment or the code needs to be fixed.

Comment: this library offers several different policies of deep merging dict
https://y.tsutsumi.io/2017/04/24/deepmerge-deep-merge-dictionaries-lists-and-more-in-python/

Comment: isn't it better if lists would be joined together instead of being replaced?

Comment: @AhmadaliShafiee There is no list in the input, but sure, it depends on the use case.