# combine two dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary as follows

```
test={}
test['key1']={}
test['key1'] ['key2'] = {}
test['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 'val1'
test['key1']['key2']['key4'] = 'val2'
```

I have another dictionary as follows

```
 check = {}
    check['key1']={}
    check['key1'] ['key2'] = {}
    check['key1']['key2']['key5'] = 'val3'
    check['key1']['key2']['key6'] = 'val4'
```

I want to combine this dictionary so i done the following

```
test.update(check)
```

but if i do this when i try to print test dictionary it is printing like

```
{'key1': {'key2': {'key5': 'val3', 'key6': 'val4'}}}
```

but expected output is

```
{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'val1', 'key4': 'val2','key5': 'val3', 'key6': 'val4'}}}
```

Comment: obviously you won't get desire output `key2` is updated with entries of `key2` from `check`

Comment: @Gahan can I check like key1 and key2 present in test if so if i give  this expr will it work  test['key1']['key2']['key5'] = 'val3'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update value of a nested dictionary of varying depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232943/update-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-of-varying-depth)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to implement a deep merge :

```
test={}
test['key1']={}
test['key1'] ['key2'] = {}
test['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 'val1'
test['key1']['key2']['key4'] = 'val2'

check = {}
check['key1']={}
check['key1'] ['key2'] = {}
check['key1']['key2']['key5'] = 'val3'
check['key1']['key2']['key6'] = 'val4'

def deep_merge(a, b):
    for key, value in b.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # get node or create one
            node = a.setdefault(key, {})
            deep_merge(value, node)
        else:
            a[key] = value

    return a

deep_merge(test,check)
print(test)
# {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'val1', 'key6': 'val4', 'key5': 'val3', 'key4': 'val2'}}}
```

It mutates `test` and leaves `check` unmodified.

Answer (score -1):

If x and y are dicts then `z = {**x, **y}` is a dict merging x and y

Comment: user wants to keep distinct key values i.e. on merging `x = {'a': 1, 'b': {'y':4}}
y = {'b': {'x':1}, 'c': 4}` as you suggested output will be `{'a': 1, 'b': {'x': 1}, 'c': 4}` but user expects `{'a': 1, 'b': {'x': 1, 'y':4}, 'c': 4}` as output

Answer (score -2):

**To deep merge dicts u need use:**

```
def merge(source, destination):
    for key, value in source.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # get node or create one
            node = destination.setdefault(key, {})
            merge(value, node)
        else:
            destination[key] = value
    return destination

test = {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'val1', 'key4': 'val2'}}}
check = {'key1': {'key2': {'key6': 'val4', 'key5': 'val3'}}}

print(merge(test, check))
# {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'val1', 'key6': 'val4', 'key4': 'val2', 'key5': 'val3'}}}
```

Its a code from [Python deep merge dictionary data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20666342/2668355) from vincent

Comment: user wants to keep distinct key values i.e. on merging `x = {'a': 1, 'b': {'y':4}}
y = {'b': {'x':1}, 'c': 4}` as you suggested output will be `{'a': 1, 'b': {'x': 1}, 'c': 4}` but user expects `{'a': 1, 'b': {'x': 1, 'y':4}, 'c': 4}` as output

Comment: @Thaian my expected op is {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'val1', 'key4': 'val2','key5': 'val3', 'key6': 'val4'}}}

Comment: @wazza check now