# Creating dynamic nested dictionary of counts

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a text file `abc.txt`:

```
abc/pqr/lmn/xyz:pass
abc/pqr/lmn/bcd:pass
```

I need to parse these statements and output should be in nested dictionary as below:

```
{'abc':{'pqr':{'lmn':{'xyz':{'pass':1},{'bcd':{'pass':1}}}}}}
```

where 1 is `'pass'` count.

I'm able to do as much as this:

```
import re

d={}
p=re.compile('[a-zA-z]+')
for line in open('abc.txt'):
    for key in p.findall(line):
        d['key']={}
```

Comment: sorry. i am new to python, but what will be the solution for this output.

Comment: yes. sorry for that.

Comment: What if the last part of each line is not ":pass"?

Comment: we have to put new count for that key

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by that. Anyway, what do you think of the answers you've gotten? Maybe your reactions to them will clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an updated version of my answer in which leaves of the tree data-structure are now different from those in rest of it. Instead of the tree being strictly a `dict`-of-nested-`dict`s, the "leaves" on each branch are now instances of a different subclass of `dict` named [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which are useful for counting the number of times each of their keys occur. I did this because of your response to my question about what should happen if the last part of each line was something other than `":pass"` (which was "we have to put new count for that key").

Nested dictionaries are often called **`Tree`** data-structures and can be defined recursively — the root is a dictionary as are the branches. The following uses a `dict` subclass instead of a plain `dict` because it makes constructing them easier since you don't need to special case the creation of the first branch of next level down (except I still do when adding the "leaves" because they are a different subclass, `collections.Counter`).

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
import re


# (Optional) trick to make Counter subclass print like a regular dict.
class Counter(Counter):
    def __repr__(self):
        return dict(self).__repr__()


# Borrowed from answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/19829714/355230
class Tree(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value


# Utility functions based on answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692747/355230
def nested_dict_get(nested_dict, keys):
    return reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], keys, nested_dict)

def nested_dict_set(nested_dict, keys, value):
    nested_dict_get(nested_dict, keys[:-1])[keys[-1]] = value

def nested_dict_update_count(nested_dict, keys):
    counter = nested_dict_get(nested_dict, keys[:-1])
    if counter:  # Update existing Counter.
        counter.update([keys[-1]])
    else:  # Create a new  Counter.
        nested_dict_set(nested_dict, keys[:-1], Counter([keys[-1]]))


d = Tree()
pat = re.compile(r'[a-zA-z]+')
with open('abc.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        nested_dict_update_count(d, [w for w in pat.findall(line.rstrip())])

print(d)  # Prints like a regular dict.
```

To test the leaf-counting capabilities of the revised code, I used the following test file which includes the same line twice, once ending again with `:pass` and another ending in `:fail`.

Expanded `abc.txt` test file:

```
abc/pqr/lmn/xyz:pass
abc/pqr/lmn/bcd:pass
abc/pqr/lmn/xyz:fail
abc/pqr/lmn/xyz:pass
```

Output:

```
{'abc': {'pqr': {'lmn': {'bcd': {'pass': 1}, 'xyz': {'fail': 1, 'pass': 2}}}}}
```

Answer (score 9):

Check out the `setdefault` method on dictionaries.

```
d = {}
d.setdefault('pqr', {}).setdefault('lmn', {}).setdefault('xyz', {})['pass'] = 1
d.setdefault('pqr', {}).setdefault('lmn', {}).setdefault('bcd', {})['pass'] = 1
d
```

gives

```
{'pqr': {'lmn': {'bcd': {'pass': 1}, 'xyz': {'pass': 1}}}}
```

Comment: is it possible to add keys dynamically instead of hard coding.

Comment: @sachin27: The hardcoded keys could be replaced with variables or values from your `p.findall()`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question:

```
sources = ["abc/pqr/lmn/xyz:pass", "abc/pqr/lmn/bcd:pass", "abc/pqr/lmn/xyz:pass"]


def prepare_source(source):
    path, value = source.split(':')
    elements = path.split('/')
    return elements, value


def add_key(elements, value):
    result = dict()
    if len(elements) > 1:
        result[elements[0]] = add_key(elements[1:], value)

    else:
        result[elements[0]] = {value: 1}

    return result


# base merge function get from here:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/dictionaries-of-dictionaries-merge
def merge(a, b, path=None):
    "merges b into a"
    if path is None: path = []
    for key in b:
        if key in a:
            if isinstance(a[key], dict) and isinstance(b[key], dict):
                merge(a[key], b[key], path + [str(key)])
            elif isinstance(a[key], int) and isinstance(b[key], int):
                a[key] += b[key]
            else:
                raise Exception('Conflict at %s' % '.'.join(path + [str(key)]))
        else:
            a[key] = b[key]
    return a


result = dict()

for source in sources:
    result = merge(result, add_key(*prepare_source(source)))

print result
```

Output will be:

```
{'abc': {'pqr': {'lmn': {'bcd': {'pass': 1}, 'xyz': {'pass': 2}}}}}
```