# how to Convert Dict ( in which key is in tuple ) to nested Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, python-3.7

there is a dictionary in which key is a tuple.

```
{('Feb', 'File1', '100'): {'1': 78, '2': 408, '3': 202, '4': 39},
 ('Feb', 'File1', '101'): {'1': 201, '2': 101, '3': 529, '4': 103},
  ('May', 'File1', '100'): {'1': 78, '2': 402, '3': 20, '4': 39}}
```

Based on month i need to convert to a nested dict format

how to convert the above dict into this format

```
{
    "Feb": {
        "File1": {
            "100": {
                "1": 78,
                "2": 408,
                "3": 202,
                "4": 39
            },
            "101": {
                "1": 201,
                "2": 101,
                "3": 529,
                "4": 103
            }}},
    "May": {
        "File1": {
            "100": {
                "1": 78,
                "2": 402,
                "3": 20,
                "157": 39
            }}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is given in the below link if you still have any doubt please revert back.

[Creating dynamic nested dictionary of counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560360/creating-dynamic-nested-dictionary-of-counts)

or you can do this:

```
dict = {('Feb', 'File1', '100'): {'1': 78, '2': 408, '3': 202, '4': 39},
        ('Feb', 'File1', '101'): {'1': 201, '2': 101, '3': 529, '4': 103},
        ('May', 'File1', '100'): {'1': 78, '2': 402, '3': 20, '4': 39}}

new = {}
for u, v, w in dict:
  new.setdefault(u,{}).setdefault(v, {})[w] = dict[(u, v, w)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution solve your problem.

```
raw = {('Feb', 'File1', '100'): {'1': 78, '2': 408, '3': 202, '4': 39},
       ('Feb', 'File1', '101'): {'1': 201, '2': 101, '3': 529, '4': 103},
       ('May', 'File1', '100'): {'1': 78, '2': 402, '3': 20, '4': 39}}

new = {}
for keys in raw.keys():
    new[keys[0]] = {keys[1]: {keys[2]: raw[keys]}}
```

Regards

Vinicius

Comment: this is the output for ur solution --- {'Feb': {'File1': {'101': {'1': 201, '2': 101, '3': 529, '4': 103}}}, 'May': {'File1': {'100': {'1': 78, '2': 402, '3': 20, '4': 39}}}} .. but for feb month in file1 i have 2 ids ( 100 , 101) . in this output for id 100 values are missing