# Dictionary Python3. Updating value of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Need you help to get an idea how to update dictionary value that represented as dictinary.

Here are two dictionaries:
d1 = {'x': {'y': 5}}
d2 = {'x': {'z': 6}}

Assume d1 + d2, then dictionary = {'x': {'y': 5, 'z': 6}}

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7204805/349420 ?

Answer (score 0):

It's rather simple...

```
d1['x'].update(d2['x'])
```

or for all keys:

```
[d1[k].update(d2[k]) for k in d1]
```