# How to apply a function to each sublist of a list in python?

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7, python-3.x

Lets say I have a list like this:

```
list_of_lists = [['how to apply'],['a function'],['to each list?']]
```

And I have a function let's say I want to apply the `F` function to each sublist of the `F` function can compute some score about two lists. How can apply this `F` function to each list of `list_of_lists` and return each score in a new list like this:

```
new_list = [score_1, score_2, score_3]
```

I tried with the `map` function the following:

```
map(F, list_of_lists).append(new_list)
```

Comment: What is the best way to do this efficienttelly?

Comment: There's nothing special about a list of lists. `map` or a list comprehension will iterate over the elements of the list, whether those be `int`s, strings, or other lists.

Comment: Sorry, I thought last night I accepted it @mu無

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to do this.

So if the function you want to apply is `len`, you would do:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [['how to apply'],['a function'],['to each list?']]
>>> map(len, list_of_lists)
[1, 1, 1]
```

In `Python3`, the above returns a map iterator, so you will need an explicit `list` call:

```
>>> map(len, list_of_lists)
<map object at 0x7f1faf5da208>
>>> list(map(len, list_of_lists))
[1, 1, 1]
```

---

If you are looking to write some code for this which has to be compatible in both Python2 and Python3, list comprehensions are the way to go. Something like:

```
[apply_function(item) for item in list_of_lists]
```

will work in both Python 2 and 3 without any changes.

However, if your input list_of_lists is huge, using `map` in Python3 would make more sense because the iterator will be much faster.

Comment: The question is for list of lists, for which the solution works. In case you are looking for a generic solution, ask a new question :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list comprehension, like this

```
[function_to_be_done(item) for item in list_of_lists]
```

For example,

```
>>> list_of_lists = [['how to apply'],['a function'],['to each list?']]
>>> [len(item) for item in list_of_lists]
[1, 1, 1]
```

**Note:** Though list comprehensions look like a way to apply a function to all the elements, its main purpose is to construct a new list. So, if you don't want to construct a new list, then just iterate with `for` loop and call the function.

---

Apart from that, you can use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function in Python 2.7, to apply a function to all the elements and construct a list. For example,

```
>>> list_of_lists = [['how to apply'],['a function'],['to each list?']]
>>> map(len, list_of_lists)
[1, 1, 1]
```

But, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns a map iterator object in Python 3.x. So, you need to explicitly convert that to a list, like this

```
>>> list_of_lists = [['how to apply'],['a function'],['to each list?']]
>>> map(len, list_of_lists)
<map object at 0x7f94026afd30>
>>> list(map(len, list_of_lists))
[1, 1, 1]
```

---

You might want to read about, what Guido thinks about `map` in this [post](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).

Basically, `map` would more often demand you to create a new function (mostly people create a `lambda` function). But in many cases, list comprehension avoids that.

Answer (score 5):

Map is your friend! `map` takes a function and an iterable (list, for example) and applies the function on each element of the list.

```
map(len, [['how to apply'],['a function'],['to each list?']])
```

Output

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

If you wanted to do more granular calculation on elements of the sublist, you can nest the map:

```
map(lambda x: map(lambda y: y + 1, x), [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]])
```

Output

```
[[2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Another possible approach (also from functional programming) are list comprehensions. List comprehension is a way of constructing a list from iterable in Python. The syntax is `[element for element in iterable]`. Any computation can be done on the element, so

```
[f(element) for element in iterable]
```

means that the resulting list will be a list of elements, where each element is the result of function f. Like map, list comprehension can be further nested, resulting in a nested element function application.

```
[element + 1 for element in el] for el in [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Output

```
[[2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: yuck: `map(lambda x: map(lambda y: y + 1, x), [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]])` ... pythonic = assembly

Comment: nice ```map``` nest

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
[ F(x) for x in list_of_lists ]
```

which will iterate over list_of_lists, call F with each sublist as an argument, then generate a list of the results.

If you want to use the sublists as all the arguments to `F` you could do it slightly differently as

```
[ F(*x) for x in list_of_lists ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Something that works on arbitrarily nested lists, e.g. [[1,2],[[5]],[7,[8,[9,11]]]] :

```
def apply_f(a,f):
 if isinstance(a,list):
     return map(lambda t:apply_f(t,f), a)
 else:
     return f(a)
```

here is an example of running this:

```
>>> ll=[[1,2],[[5]],[7,[8,[9,11]]]]
>>> apply_f(ll,lambda t:t**2)
[[1, 4], [[25]], [49, [64, [81, 121]]]]
```

---

and here is how to do the same only on selected levels:

```
def apply_f(a,f,depth,levels):
    if isinstance(a,list):
        return map(lambda t:apply_f(t,f,depth+1,levels), a)
    else:
        if depth in levels:
            return f(a)
        else:
            return a
```

getting e.g.

```
>>> apply_f(ll,lambda t:t**2, 0, [2,4])
[[1, 4], [[5]], [49, [8, [81, 121]]]]
```

there are some optimisations to do here, by avoiding passing `f` and `levels`
around (making the recursive function an inner function in a wrapper,
so that it can use `f` and `levels` from the outer scope), but that's minor. (Note that this is Python 2, for Python 3 you need to replace `map` with something else).

---

For a more generic input, the following would do the trick:

```
def apply_f(a,f):
    try: 
       return(f(a))
    except:
       return map(lambda t:apply_f(t,f), a)
```

So now also the following sort of works:

```
>> apply_f([(1,2),[[5]],[7,(8,[9,11])]],lambda t:t**2)
[[1, 4], [[25]], [49, [64, [81, 121]]]]
```

(things get slightly rewritten, as `map()` always produces lists...)

Comment: Can you generalize to map at a user-specified level or list of levels?

Comment: yes, this is easy: you need to store the nestedness level of apply_f in its parameter, and increase it in recursive calls; and return f(a) or a itself, conditioned on the nestedness level.

Comment: here you are. In case, I am available for  consulting work, and actually passed Google Foobar for the lols a couple of years ago :-)

Comment: Dima, thanks, will test. Im new to "pythonic" but can't wait to get back to a high level language vs this assembly-level sh*. What you just implemented is built in the system I like to use and it works generically for all expressions not just lists. van Rossum is a clown.

Comment: You can make it more general by testing for Iterable instead

In [5]: from collections import Iterable

In [6]: isinstance([1,2],Iterable)
Out[6]: True

In [7]: isinstance((1,2),Iterable)
Out[7]: True

Comment: WIth all respect, if you programmed in assembly you won't ever call Python an assembly. Try coding this in C (a glorified assembly) :-).

 I won't be surprised if the function you want is available in Common Lisp...

Comment: I added one more example, that lets one apply functions onto nested iterables.

Comment: (1) How do you extract raw lists in your output? I get nested `map` objects. (2) Can you modify to preserve the container type - in your example return `(1,4)` as `tuple` not `list`. (3) does it generalize to `dicts` as well? eg  `apply_f([{'a':1,'b':2},[[5]],...}`

Comment: In my forthcoming book on data I extend a chart published by Alan Kay (Scientific American, 1984) that compares the level of abstraction of various languages since the 1950s. Python is at a higher level than C, as C is higher than assembly and the latter is higher than machine code. But the language I've been using for data, Wolfram Language, makes working in Py feel like assembly, relatively speaking.

Comment: yes, I used a bit of Mathematica in the past, but I've sworn off using it, along with Matlab, Maple, and Magma, since landing at some point in a department without a license for  Matlab (something of a staple in my then research community),  or to any of the other M's, in fact. Yes, I could have ordered a CD with Mathematica from Moscow, but I chose not to. I'd love to work in Haskell or something similar, just don't have an opportunity....

Comment: You get nested map objects in Python 3. Run Python 2, you'll get what shown. Or wrap `map()` into `list()`, i.e. replace each `map()` with `list(map())`.

Comment: Well, I'm using Python 3 and cannot roll back to 2 at work. The problem is seems programmer would have to remember and match input types (`list`, `tuple` etc) to a nested combination of these to convert the nested maps. Also can you handle `dict`? And can this more generic type version be combined with user-specified levels (including a ":" spec to apply a function at all levels)? - All these features are built into WL.

Comment: Haskell, while functional, doesn't have the large scale symbolic processing and pattern matching features of WL, which are very handy for data work.

Comment: I merely explained how to solve a particular problem in Python. If you have a rather different problem, it's probably better to post another question. We merely scratched the surface of what Python can do for you here. (Needless to say, if you have to do pattern-matching, both Python and Haskell are more than adequate tools, and Haskell offers a lot of extra in form of type checking etc.)

Comment: Re `pattern-matching, both Python and Haskell are more than adequate tools`, I meant symbolic pattern matching of arbitrary code expressions. There's no such functionality in Python or Haskell. In WL, the code itself can be treated as input data to be transformed (metaprogramming).

Comment: I think meta-programming is reserved for transforming code, rather than data, and in this both Python (decorators) and Haskell (just by design) are just fine.

Comment: as to mathematical expressions, check out e.g. http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/prep/Calculus.html
(sagemath is a Python library)

Comment: Yes I'm aware of Sage. But it's limited to Calculus. In WL you can symbolically pattern match / replace any code not just math. You can't do this in Py in general. Re meta-programming, the code represents data containers as well as functional operators acting on those, which is routine in WL, not limited to math or data. So in WL there is no real difference b/w code and data. Whereas in Py there is.

Comment: I used to be somewhat familiar with Lisp macros, and before that had a student job involving a lot of code generation  in MUMPS, and found them a bit too cryptic. Nowadays I think a degree of separation between code and data helps to maintain sanity :-)

Comment: Notable computer scientist Don Knuth still prefers assembly. A basic task like [dict recursive merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/dictionaries-of-dictionaries-merge/24088493#24088493), which clearly is painful in Py, is 1-line of code in WL.

Comment: with https://pypi.org/project/deepmerge/ it should be 1 line in Python too, I guess.

Comment: I mean the function *definition* to perform the merge is 1-line in WL.

Comment: by the way, Knuth prefers assembly for analysis of algorithms, rather than actual coding. E.g. he wrote TeX and other related utilities in WEB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEB

Comment: Great, have fun in assembly-world. but If you are interested, I'll be doing live coding tutorials on functional data flow through WRI based on my book.

Comment: I am sure if you post a challenge on 1-line implementation of your recursive merge in a proper PL forum, you'd be surprised to find that WL is not the only game in town, that it can be done without having to pay Wolfram tax (perhaps even in Haskell :-))

Comment: well, that's what 20+ years of heavy Mathematica abuse can do to an individual. :-)

Comment: Quite the opposite: just about everything I looked up to see if there's an easy way, Stackoverflow says not doable. There's at least a 5:1 Py/WL LOC ratio for data. So even though it's free, you pay much more in dev time.