# What is the best way to appy changes in a list in Python

Tags: python

In Python, is there a shorter way to implement this:

```
x = [func(i) for i in x] ,
```

for given function *func* and list *x* ?

Comment: You may use `map(func, x)` ..

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060970/how-to-apply-a-function-to-each-sublist-of-a-list-in-python/30061049#30061049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `map` function, its shorter to write, but it a little more time consuming from my experience.

Example -

```
x = map(func, x)
```

For Python 3.x , `map` returns an iterator, so you need to explicitly convert it to `list` -

```
x = list(map(func, x))
```