# Python: perform actions on all the elements and sub-elements within a list

Tags: python, numpy

I want to perform some actions within a huge list, which contains multiple lists, and within those multiple lists, they also have some lists, for example:

```
arr = [[[1, 2], 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

How can I perform some actions with all the elements within these lists, for example +1 ? And the result will be :

```
[[[2, 3], 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

I know I can use `for` to loop through every list, but sometimes those elements might be `string` or other types?

And I know I can check `type()` for every element inside the list do it recursively and perform some actions, but is there any **simple** way to solve this problem?

Too broad my ass

Comment: Have you tried something already? If so, please share your code. If you have strings, I don't think you'll be able to avoid type-checking.

Comment: `isinstance` is preferable over `type`, but besides that yes, you're going to have to do some traversal.

Comment: I see, I only need to check if they are `list`

Comment: [How to apply a function to each sublist of a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357135/1248974)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple recursive routine can do that like:

#### Code:

```
def operate_on(data, operation):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [operate_on(x, operation) for x in data]
    else:
        return operation(data)
```

#### Test Code:

```
arr = [[[1, 2], 3], [2, 3, 4]]
print(operate_on(arr, lambda x: x + 1))
```

#### Results:

```
[[[2, 3], 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```