# Merge dictionaries with sub dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, merge, python-3.6

I would like to deep-merge 2 dictionaries which both have at some level one or more dictionaries values with the same key. How can I merge also those internal dictionaries simply? Something like the "**" notation but a deep merge.

Example:

```
d1 = {"v1": "value1", "sub": {"sv1": "sub value 1"}}
d2 = {"v2": "value2", "sub": {"sv2": "sub value 2"}}
d3 = {**d1, **d2}
print(d3)
```

Actual result:

```
{'v1': 'value1', 'sub': {'sv2': 'sub value 2'}, 'v2': 'value2'}
```

Desired result:

```
{'v1': 'value1',
 'sub': {'sv1': 'sub value 1', 'sv2': 'sub value 2'},
 'v2': 'value2'}
```

Noticed the **sub -> sv1 -> sub value 1**

This is a simple example while the real case have several more levels of dictionaries. Moreover the solution needs to be generic since the structure of the dictionaries is not known in advanced.

Comment: This is a surprisingly complex operation in general case.

Comment: Close as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/dictionaries-of-dictionaries-merge)?

Comment: I've been also writing a library that can do a generic 3-way merge on JSON objects (this is even more complicated though).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it is not a dup, he doesn't considered the cases where both sub-dict have the same keys. He just talking about a deep copying.

Comment: "where both sub-dict have the same keys." what do you mean? Your subdicts have *different* keys, `sv1` and `sv2`; the accepted answer **also** handles same keys, i.e. conflict of `sv1` and `sv1` with different values...

Comment: The example is just a light example. I want to handle also a case of `s1->s2->s3->value1` merge with `s1->s2->s3->value2` etc.

Comment: And you didn't mention it in **your** question, but instead ask for "something else"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Point taken, I edited my question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing this:

```
import collections
import copy

def deep_dict_merge(dct1, dct2, override=True) -> dict:
    """
    :param dct1: First dict to merge
    :param dct2: Second dict to merge
    :param override: if same key exists in both dictionaries, should override? otherwise ignore. (default=True)
    :return: The merge dictionary
    """
    merged = copy.deepcopy(dct1)
    for k, v2 in dct2.items():
        if k in merged:
            v1 = merged[k]
            if isinstance(v1, dict) and isinstance(v2, collections.Mapping):
                merged[k] = deep_dict_merge(v1, v2, override)
            elif isinstance(v1, list) and isinstance(v2, list):
                merged[k] = v1 + v2
            else:
                if override:
                    merged[k] = copy.deepcopy(v2)
        else:
            merged[k] = copy.deepcopy(v2)
    return merged
```

Answer (score 1):

You already had the first three steps to create *d3* with all the common keys:

```
>>> d1 = {"v1": "value1", "sub": {"sv1": "sub value 1"}}
>>> d2 = {"v2": "value2", "sub": {"sv2": "sub value 2"}}
>>> d3 = {**d1, **d2}  # initial merge of common keys
```

There just needs to be a follow-on step to merge in all the "sub" entries:

```
>>> for d in (d1, d2): # merge the "sub" entries
        d3['sub'].update(d['sub'])
```

That gives the desired result:

```
>>> d3
{'v1': 'value1', 'sub': {'sv2': 'sub value 2', 'sv1': 'sub value 1'}, 'v2': 'value2'}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: `d2['sub']` ending up having the modifications might be an unwanted effect.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good approach. but I'm looking for a more generic case. The example I gave here was just to make a point. In my real case I don't know the keys and moreover it may have several levels not just two.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel I gave the answer to the question as asked and editted multiple times.  It sounds like your actual problem is underspecified.

Answer (score 1):

for python3:

```
d1 = {"v1": "value1", "sub": {"sv1": "sub value 1",'newsub':"value 2",'newsubdict':{'ok':'pssible','not_again':{'key1':'just checking'}}}}
d2 = {"v2": "value2", "sub": {"sv2": "sub value 2",'newsubdict':{'fine':'i am working','not_again':{'key2':'Am i right?'}}}}

from copy import deepcopy
d3 = deepcopy(d1)

def combine_key(d2,d3):
  for key in d2.keys():
      if(key in d3):
              d3[key] =d2[key]
      elif(isinstance(d3[key],dict)):
              combine_key(d2[key],d3[key])
      else:
              d3[key].update(d2[key])

combine_key(d2,d3)
print(d3) #{'v1': 'value1', 'sub': {'sv1': 'sub value 1', 'newsub': 'value 2', 'newsubdict': {'ok': 'pssible', 'not_again': {'key1': 'just checking', 'key2': 'Am i right?'}, 'fine': 'i am working'}, 'sv2': 'sub value 2'}, 'v2': 'value2'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a specific answer, I'm looking for a more generic one.

Comment: Generic mean you have no idea about D1 and D2 dictionary structure. So it can be number of nested dictionary with same key  is it?

Comment: Yeap, that is exactly the situation I'm talking about.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel You can take a look at updated code now.I have modified dictionary for 3 to 4 nested dictionary.

Comment: This is a good approach, close to what I ended writing. But I think the use of the "no" is wrong, what if one actually have this key. Better use `if key in d3`