# How to merge complex nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'cm': {'fill': {'user': {'registration': {'flag': 'f'}}}}}
dict2 = {'cm': {'fill': {'user': {'url': 'www.example.com'}}}}
```

The output I want:

```
dict3 = {'cm': {'fill': {'user':{'registration': {'flag': 'f'}}, {'url': 'www.example.com'}}}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
dict3 = {**dict1, **dict2} # This does not work. It only gives me a `dict1`.
```

The problem is that `dict1` and `dict2` can have many embedded keys.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: The reason your expression `dict3 = {**dict1, **dict2}` does not work is because the key/value pairs in `dict2` will override those in `dict1`. Since they have the same top-level key `cm`, `dict2` is overwritten. They need different top-level keys. Not sure if that's your actual data or just an example.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/7586861

Comment: Seems to be a potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/dictionaries-of-dictionaries-merge/7205107#7205107. The `merge` function in the linked answer returns the expected dict on the input you have here. We need more information about expected input though.

Answer (score 2):

Correct: that merge won't do what you want.  You have accumulation to do multiple levels down.  I suspect that the easiest way for you to get what you want -- merging at unspecified (arbitrary) depth -- is to write a recursive routine to do the merge you want.

```
def dict_merge(d1, d2):
    for key in d1:
        if key in d2:
            one_merge = dict_merge(d1[key], d2[key])
        else:
            one_merge = d1[key]
    for ... # also pick up keys in d2 that are not in d1.
```

I'll leave it to you whether to handle this logic with set intersection and difference.

Comment: If the structure is consistent, I believe `collections.defaultdict` is a good option.

Comment: Yup -- We'll wait for OP to sort out whether to rely on that consistency.  I went for a more general -- and less obvious -- solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the structure of your dictionaries is consistent, you can use `collections.defaultdict` with a nested approach.

It's possible to convert the nested `defaultdict` to regular `dict` objects. But this may not be necessary for your use case.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = {'cm': {'fill': {'user': {'registration': {'flag': 'f'}}}}}
dict2 = {'cm': {'fill': {'user': {'url': 'www.example.com'}}}}

rec_dd = lambda: defaultdict(rec_dd)
d = rec_dd()

for i in [dict1, dict2]:
    d['cm']['fill']['user'].update(i['cm']['fill']['user'])

# defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#             {'cm': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#                          {'fill': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#                                       {'user': defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#                                                    {'registration': {'flag': 'f'},
#                                                     'url': 'www.example.com'})})})})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion while `zip`ing the data:

```
dict1 = {'cm': {'fill': {'user': {'registration': {'flag': 'f'}}}}}
dict2 = {'cm': {'fill': {'user': {'url': 'www.example.com'}}}}
def update_dict(d1, d2):
   return {a:update_dict(b, d) if a == c and list(b.keys())[0] == list(d.keys())[0] else {**b, **d} for [a, b], [c, d] in zip(d1.items(), d2.items())}
```

Output:

```
{'cm': {'fill': {'user': {'registration': {'flag': 'f'}, 'url': 'www.example.com'}}}}
```