# Split list into sublists based on string split

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
a = [['cat1.subcat1.item1', 0], ['cat1.subcat1.item2', 'hello], [cat1.subcat2.item1, 1337], [cat2.item1, 'test']]
```

So there may be several subcategories with items, split by a dot. But the number of categoryies and the level of depth isn't fixed and not equal among the categories.

I want the list to look like this:

```
a = [['cat1', [
        ['subcat1', [
            ['item1', 0],
            ['item2', 'hello']
        ]],
        ['subcat2', [
            ['item1', 1337]
        ]],
    ]],
    ['cat2', [
        ['item1', 'test']
    ]]
]
```

I hope this makes sense.

In the end I need a json string out of this. If it is somehow easier it could also directly be converted to the json string.

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? To me it looks more like a dict (of dicts (~ of dicts)) as you seem to have key/value pairs. Can you have multiple `'cat1'` items with different values?

Comment: I would recommend dictionaries over nested lists if you want json in the end

Comment: You are right of course, its dicts of dicts etc :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a nested dictionary structure. This can be processed efficiently using `collections.defaultdict` and `functools.reduce`.

Conversion to a regular dictionary is possible, though usually not necessary.

**Solution**

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

def getFromDict(dataDict, mapList):
    """Iterate nested dictionary"""
    return reduce(getitem, mapList, dataDict)

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
d = tree()

for i, j in a:
    path = i.split('.')
    getFromDict(d, path[:-1])[path[-1]] = j
```

**Result**

```
def default_to_regular_dict(d):
    """Convert nested defaultdict to regular dict of dicts."""
    if isinstance(d, defaultdict):
        d = {k: default_to_regular_dict(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    return d

res = default_to_regular_dict(d)

{'cat1': {'subcat1': {'item1': 0,
                      'item2': 'hello'},
          'subcat2': {'item1': 1337}},
 'cat2': {'item1': 'test'}}
```

**Explanation**

- `getFromDict(d, path[:-1])` takes a list `path[:-1]` and recursively accesses dictionary values corresponding to the list items from dictionary `d`. I've implemented this bit functionally via `functools.reduce` and `operator.getitem`.
- We then access the key `path[-1]`, the last element of the list, from the resulting dictionary tree. This will be a dictionary since `d` is a defaultdict of dictionaries. We can then assign value `j` to this dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Not as pretty as @jpp their solution, but hey *at least I tried*. Using the `merge` function to merge deep dicts, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7205107/1150683).

```
def merge(a, b, path=None):
    "merges b into a"
    if path is None: path = []
    for key in b:
        if key in a:
            if isinstance(a[key], dict) and isinstance(b[key], dict):
                merge(a[key], b[key], path + [str(key)])
            elif a[key] == b[key]:
                pass # same leaf value
            else:
                raise Exception('Conflict at %s' % '.'.join(path + [str(key)]))
        else:
            a[key] = b[key]
    return a


a = [['cat1.subcat1.item1', 0], ['cat1.subcat1.item2', 'hello'], ['cat1.subcat2.item1', 1337], ['cat2.item1', 'test']]

# convert to dict
b = {x[0]:x[1] for x in a}
res = {}

# iterate over dict
for k, v in list(b.items()):
  s = k.split('.')
  temp = {}
  # iterate over reverse indices,
  # build temp dict from the ground up
  for i in reversed(range(len(s))):
    if i == len(s)-1:
      temp = {s[i]: v}
    else:
      temp = {s[i]: temp}

    # merge temp dict with main dict b
    if i == 0:
      res  = merge(res, temp)
      temp = {}

print(res)
# {'cat1': {'subcat1': {'item1': 0, 'item2': 'hello'}, 'subcat2': {'item1': 1337}}, 'cat2': {'item1': 'test'}}
```