# appending a dictionary to a nested dictionary Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a nested Python dictionary which looks as so

```
master_config_skeleton = {
"ingestion_config":
    {
    "location":{}, 
    "start_sequence":{}, 
    "datafeed":
        {
        "t04047":
            {
            "validation":
                {
                "triple_check":{},
                "record_count_validation":{}
                }, 
            "date_pattern":{}, 
            "cdc_config": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a data frame that I have converted to a dictionary as below.

`[{'source': 'FLEXCAB', 'app': 'Replicator', 'feed_id': 2382, 'seq_type': 'SEQUENCE', 'hdfs_home_dir': '/data/b2b'}`]

I am looking to append this dictionary to the nested Python dictionary `master_config_skeleton` to transform it as below:-

```
master_config_skeleton = {
"ingestion_config":
    {
    "source": "FLEXCAB",
    "app": "Replicator",
    "feed_id": "2382",
    "seq_type": "SEQUENCE",
    "hdfs_home_dir": "/data/b2b",
    "location":{}, 
    "start_sequence":{}, 
    "datafeed":
        {
        "t04047":
            {
            "validation":
                {
                "triple_check":{},
                "record_count_validation":{}
                }, 
            "date_pattern":{}, 
            "cdc_config": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary from first value of list and `merge` together:

```
L = [{'source': 'FLEXCAB', 'app': 'Replicator', 'feed_id': 2382, 
      'seq_type': 'SEQUENCE', 'hdfs_home_dir': '/data/b2b'}]

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/7205107    
out = merge(master_config_skeleton, {'ingestion_config':L[0]})
print (out)

{
  "ingestion_config": {
    "location": {},
    "start_sequence": {},
    "datafeed": {
      "t04047": {
        "validation": {
          "triple_check": {},
          "record_count_validation": {}
        },
        "date_pattern": {},
        "cdc_config": {}
      }
    },
    "source": "FLEXCAB",
    "app": "Replicator",
    "feed_id": 2382,
    "seq_type": "SEQUENCE",
    "hdfs_home_dir": "/data/b2b"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update method of dict, It takes all the keys from another dictionary and add it to the original dictionary, Pleas notice that this method overrides existing keys

For example this code

```
d1 = {'A': 'Alice', 'B': 'Bob'}
d2 = {'B': 'Barak', 'C': 'Carl'}
d1.update(d2)
print(d1)
```

Would print this output

```
{'A': 'Alice', 'B': 'Barak', 'C': 'Carl'}
```

Comment: doing so gives me an error stating `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required`