# Passing nested parameters in the extra_params of the load_context in Kedro

Tags: python, kedro

I am trying to load a Kedro context with some extra parameters. My intention is to update the configs in `parameters.yml` with only the ones passed in `extra_params` (*so rest of the configs should remain same*). I will then use this instance of context to run some nodes/pipelines (*Note: I don't want to modify the `parameters.yml` file, just update it for this run*). I am able to do so for every configs defined at the top/root level in `parameters.yml` but only the passed configs are persisted in case of nested parameters.

To replicate the issue,

**parameters.yml**

```
config_root1: "name"
config_root2: "surname"
config_root3:
   config_leaf1: 10
   config_leaf2: 20
   config_leaf3: 30
```

Extra params defined as,

```
extra_params = {'config_root1': 'new_name', 'config_root3': {'config_leaf1': 11}}
```

Loading the context with `extra_params` by,

```
from kedro.framework.context import load_context    
context = load_context(proj_path, extra_params=extra_params)
```

The parameters in context is updated to,

```
config_root1: "new_name"
config_root2: "surname"
config_root3:
   config_leaf1: 11
```

Points to note,

1. `config_root1` was at root level and value was passed in `extra_params`, hence it was updated.
2. `config_root2` was at root level and no value was passed, hence it remains the same.
3. `config_leaf1` was at leaf level, value passed hence updated.
4. `config_leaf{2, 3}` were at leaf level, no value passed hence dropped.

It seems the issue has to do with how [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python) and [nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/how-to-merge-dictionaries-of-dictionaries/24088493#24088493) are merged.

Any workarounds other than always passing all of the parameters in `extra_params` (*even if only few needs to be changed*)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the replacement of key `config_root3` to new value, and it cannot be omited easily.

I guess the best way to do it would be creation of two separate configs which override each other with [Additional configuration environment](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/04_user_guide/03_configuration.html#additional-configuration-environments), but it requires changes in the way you work with load_context.

Additionally, you can use config loader and merge parameters manually, then provide merge result as `extra_params`.

Answer (score 0):

`extra_params` or the `kedro run --params` cli now accepts nested dict update.

With CLI:

`kedro run --params=nested_key.nested_subkey:<value>`

With Python API:

```
params = {'nested_level1': 
     {'nested_level2' : 'some_value'}
}

with KedroSession.create(extra_params=params
                        ) as session:
    session.run()
```