# Understanding appropriate **kwargs in python documentation

Tags: python

What's the best way to understand which **kwargs are valid for a given python function?

I often need to use python functions that can accept additional keyword arguments as **kwargs, but I am unsure which **kwargs I can use.

For example, I am currently looking at the matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid function docs https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot2grid.html but it doesn't give any further information.

Comment: It says: `**kwargs: Additional keyword arguments are handed to add_subplot.` So you would have to check the documentation of `add_subplot`.

Comment: According to the documentation, "Additional keyword arguments are handed to add_subplot.".

Comment: it's just a way to explode a dictionary https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223650/how-to-merge-dict-of-dict-in-python/63223847#63223847

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the specifics of the function, if it's not documented there's not much you can do short of diving through the code.

Here, the documentation does tell you:

> Additional keyword arguments are handed to `add_subplot`.

So you can look at the documentation for [add_subplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=add_subplot#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) and see what kwargs are likely acceptable.