# How to get a field from a nested json (mix of dict and list) with a default value

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a json like str and it has mixture of key and dict. I want to set a default value if target key is not existed. I can use get method or try and catch block but it does not look nice. Any better solution? Thanks for your time.

```
import json
j_str = '''{
   "key1":[
      {
         "val1":1,
         "key2":2
      }
   ]
}'''
j_dict = json.loads(j_str)

print(j_dict['key1'][0]['val1'])
```

Comment: The best way would be to have a default dictionary structure and update that with the new json data. I answered a question like that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383920/merge-deep-json-files-in-python), but also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona/26853961#26853961) post looks into merging dictionaries. Otherwise you can use `.get(val, default)`, or the `try/except` approach, because these are valid solutions.

Comment: It could have list or not, so very dynamic situation. Something like get may helpful but I don't know how to handle the list with get. Thanks for giving some pointer!

Comment: The first solution I provided ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383920/merge-deep-json-files-in-python)) can handle `dict`, `list` and some nesting in them, with a constraint on `lists` items (the inserting `list` need to have the same number of elements, otherwise it is impossible to determine the overlap position). The only thing I could find for default values for `lists` is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125619/why-doesnt-list-have-safe-get-method-like-dictionary) post.

Comment: Your answer is a valid approach to solve the issue. I appreciate your help. I will try to implement this on my project and will write the details later. Thanks!

Comment: This lib sounds interesting! https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py