# Python dictionary merging deletes empty lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I had a strange issue while merging 2 dictionaries in Python.

Let's say having a valid empty body for performing ElasticSearch queries:

```
>>> a = {'aggs': {}, 'query': {'bool': {'must': [], 'should': []}}}
```

When I print it:

```
>>> a
{'aggs': {}, 'query': {'bool': {'must': [], 'should': []}}}
```

Is running perfectly fine.
But when I want to merge another dictionary for filling `must` or `should` list, the empty one just disappears:

**Py 3.9 style:**

```
>>> empty_body | {'query': {'must': [{'match_phrase': {'field': 'value'}}]}}
{'aggs': {}, 'query': {'must': [{'match_phrase': {'field': 'value'}}]}}
```

**Py 3.5 style:**

```
>>> {**empty_body, **{'query': {'must': [{'match_phrase': {'test': 'test'}}]}}}
{'aggs': {}, 'query': {'must': [{'match_phrase': {'test': 'test'}}]}}
```

In both cases the `should` list disappears.

Is there a way to keep empty lists and KISS?

Comment: You should deep merge it
Checkout the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/how-to-merge-dictionaries-of-dictionaries/7205107#7205107)

Comment: The `|` operator only merges top-level keys. Thus it will replace the entire query value form the second list and not attempt to merge them

Comment: you have nested dictionary - maybe it need recursion.

Comment: Your code for is incorrectly formatted, could your fix the layout so we can reproduce the problem? `{'aggs': {}` has started a new dictionary

Comment: Though it looks like you have 2 keys called `'query'` so the query field from `empty_body` is probably getting over-ridden. What is it that you want to happen?

Comment: Try to merge two dictionaries into third:

`>>> a = {'aggs': {}, 'query': {'bool': {'must': [], 'should': []}}}`
`>>> empty_body = {}`
`>>> a | empty_body`
`{'aggs': {}, 'query': {'bool': {'must': [], 'should': []}}}`
    
This is a little bit more,  but work

Comment: Thanks all, it's solved with @Abdollah Keshtkar I finally use "deepmerge" package.