# How to merge list of dictionaries by key?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

How can I turn the following list:

```
[{'xx1': {'test1': 8}}, {'xx1': {'test3': 2}}, {'yy2': {'test1': 5}}, {'yy2': {'test5': 6}}]
```

into

```
[{'xx1' : {'test1': 8, 'test3':2}, 'yy2' : {'test1': 5, 'test5': 6}}]
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this? Or, how can it be done by using `reduce()`?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge dictionaries of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/how-to-merge-dictionaries-of-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

something like the below

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(dict)
lst = [{'xx1': {'test1': 8}}, {'xx1': {'test3': 2}}, {'yy2': {'test1': 5}}, {'yy2': {'test5': 6}}]

for entry in lst:
    for k, v in entry.items():
        kk, vv = next(iter(v.items()))
        data[k][kk] = vv
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'xx1': {'test1': 8, 'test3': 2}, 'yy2': {'test1': 5, 'test5': 6}})
```