# Enrich Python dictionary with data from second dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Give 2 Python dictionaries such as

```
a1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1, 'e': {'f': 6, 'h': {'j': 3}}}
a2 = {'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 4, 'e': {'f': 6, 'g': 8, 'h': {'i': 10}}}
```

I am required to update a1 with any values it is missing from a2. The missing keys are given as a list within a list i.e. `[['d'], ['e', 'g'], ['e', 'h', 'i']]`. The last item means you are adding a nested item to a1. What would be the most efficient way to go about this?

NB:

1. The `dict.update()` method doesn't work because it overwrites existing keys in `a1`
2. The output of the missing keys is coming from the [deepdiff](https://deepdiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, which I am using to get the difference between the two dicts

*Expected Output*

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 1, 'e': {'f': 6, 'g': 8, 'h': {'j': 3, 'i': 10}}, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output also?

Comment: If you are already using `deepdiff`, [`deepdiff.Delta`](https://zepworks.com/deepdiff/current/delta.html#diff-to-load-in-delta) seems to be what you want.

Comment: @KaushalKumar Thank you, I just did

@Amadan `a1 + Delta(DeepDiff(a1, a2))` gives the same result as `a1.update(a2)` i.e. overwrites some keys

Comment: For anyone interested, I resolved this using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7205107/10295795). However, I did a small edit i.e. skip the conflict exception and just pass to retain data in original dict. Thank you