# Merging top level of nested dict between Python 3.8 and 3.9

Tags: python

I have nested dict as following:

```
x1 = {'a1': 'val1', 
      'a2':'val2'}
x2 = {'b1': {'b1a':'val3'}, 
      'b2': {'b2a':'val3'}}
```

Both `x1` and `x2` can be multiple level nested dictionaries. But I just want to merge them at the top level, with this expected output:

```
x_merged = {'a1': 'val1', 
            'a2': 'val2', 
            'b1': {'b1a': 'val3'}, 
            'b2': {'b2a': 'val3'}}
```

In Python 3.9, I can do that easily with:

```
x_merged = x1 | x2
```

But in Python 3.8 and lower, that syntax is not accepted. I have to do:

```
x_merged = dict(x1.items() | x2.items())
```

But that statemment only works for one level dictionaries. I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` for multi-level dictionaries.

Any short solution to this for Python 3.8 (beside writing a whole function such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/how-to-merge-dictionaries-of-dictionaries))

Comment: `x1.update(x2)`!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old `{**x1, **x2}` should work

Output:

```
{'a1': 'val1', 
 'a2': 'val2', 
 'b1': {'b1a': 'val3'}, 
 'b2': {'b2a': 'val3'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python@3.5 and greater ([PEP 448](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/)):

```
x_merged = {**x1, **x2}
```