# how to merge two multi-depth objects in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, merge

I am building some app that needs configuration with lots of similarities and some differences. I'd like to be able to use some base config and override it with the specific values where needed.

Each config element is a list of configurations, and each configuration is a dict that can have dict or array as value. And I'd like to be able to merge them in a "smart" way. I.e:

```
base_conf = [
  {'a': 'foo', 'b': 12, 'c': {'x': 1, 'y': 2}, 'd': [1, 2, 3]},
  {'a': 'bar', 'd': [10, 20]}
]

conf = {
  'conf1': smart_merge(base_conf, [
    {'b': 24, 'c': {'y': 20}},
    {'c': {'x': 10, 'z': 30}}
  ]),
}
```

The expected result of conf1 is:

```
conf1: [
  {'a': 'foo', 'b': 24, 'c': {'x': 1, 'y': 20}, 'd': [1, 2, 3]},
  {'a': 'bar', 'c': {'x': 10, 'z': 30}, 'd': [10, 20]}
]
```

So again the goal is merging nested object of types: dictionaries, lists, strings and numbers. It's always adding or overriding, never removing.

Comment: What have you tried and what output do you get?

Comment: `base_conf = {'d': [1,2,3]}`, `next_conf = {'d': [5]} next_conf2 = {'d': []}` what will be the result?

Comment: How does smart_merge know where each `c` goes? is it always index based merge? (`{'b': 24, c: {y: 20}}` goes to base_conf[0] and `{x: 10, z: 30}` to `base_conf[1]` because that's the order they're in )

Comment: What if `base_conf = { 'a' : { 'x' : 1 } }` and `new_conf = { 'a' : 4 }`, what is the result?

Comment: @David, yes, the items inside list are considered to be in the same order, and do override accordingly

Comment: @Nick in my real world use case the types will be the same even if we override, but if we're talking more theoretically, then the result should be: {'a': 4}

Comment: In that case @Daviid answer should work for you if you don't have multi-level nesting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep merge dictionaries of dictionaries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204805/deep-merge-dictionaries-of-dictionaries-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works with something like:

```
{'c': {'x': 10, 'z': {'h': 1, 'j': 9}}}
```

because there's 2 levels of nesting, so I'll leave that to you :D

```
base_conf = [
  {'a': 'foo', 'b': 12, 'c': {'x': 1, 'y': 2}, 'd': [1,2,3]},
  {'a': 'bar', 'd': [10,20]}
]

add_to_base = [
    {'b': 24, 'c': {'y': 20}},
    {'c': {'x': 10, 'z': 30}}
  ]

# Initialize an empty list to store the merged dictionaries
result = []

# This is short and pretty
# but it doesn't work because instead of 
#     'c': {'x': 1, 'y': 20}
# we end upt with
#     'c': {'y': 20}
#
# for base_config_row, add_config_row in zip(base_conf, add_to_base):
#   result.append({**base_config_row, **add_config_row})

# We'll process row by row
for base_config_row, add_config_row in zip(base_conf, add_to_base):
    # Copy were we update values based on add_config_row
    merged_dict = base_config_row.copy()
    for key, value in add_config_row.items():
        if key in merged_dict and isinstance(value, dict) and isinstance(merged_dict[key], dict):
            # If it's a dictionary update it's values with what add_config_row might have (e.g add_to_base['c'])
            merged_dict[key].update(value)
        else:
            # if number or string or list simply overwrite (e.g add_to_base['b'])
            merged_dict[key] = value
    #Save updated config row
    result.append(merged_dict)


print(result)
```

This works, it's not really a function but you can work that out yourself.

Comment: This is how I thought I would start to do this, by having a recursive function that receives 2 objects, then according to their type it does what it has to and calls itself on the list elements or on the dict values. I just hoped someone knows some library that has a function already for this

Comment: I don't think you'll find a library for such a specific case.